# Puppet Ubuntu check Version 16 or 17

Tags: puppet

i need to check if its Ubuntu Version 16 (for older pcs) or 17 (for newer pcs with different WLAN module), but this IF check doesnt work so far. Can you support please?

```
  if /opt/puppetlabs/bin/facter os.distro.id == 'Ubuntu' {
    if /opt/puppetlabs/bin/facter os.distro..release.major == '16.04.' {
        $ubunutname = 'xenial'
        $wlankarte  = 'wlp4s0'
    }
    if /opt/puppetlabs/bin/facter os.distro..release.major == '17.04' {
      $ubunutname = 'zesty'
      $wlankarte  = 'wlp58s0'
    }
    else{
      fail("Unsupported major of ${facts}['operatingsystem']")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're close, but you don't have to specify the path for Facter, the facts get added automatically to the context. And the LSB codename is also a fact, so you can simplify this a lot:

```
case $::lsbdistcodename {
  'xenial': {
    $wlankarte  = 'wlp4s0'
  }
  'zesty': {
    $wlankarte  = 'wlp58s0'
  }
  default: {
    fail("Unsupported Debian-flavor machine: ${::lsbdistcodename}")
  }
}
```